# Crea un juego con canvas JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, motor-de-juego

Tengo la base que el personaje para que se pueda mover, pero necesito que al momento de colisionar se reinicie.

La estructura básica es esta, pero no logro encontrar la manera de que detecte colisiones, también necesito la manera de que los personajes monstruos puedan aparecer de *manera aleatoria*.

El movimiento funciona, pero otro problema que también tengo es que el personaje **se sale de la pantalla y no permite verlo**, necesito hallar la manera que se quedé dentro de ella.

```js
var micanvas;
var imagemia;
var posX = 650;
var posY = 10;
var monsX = 10;
var monsY = 10;
var abc;
var mos;

window.onload = function () {
  micanvas = document.getElementById("areainicial");
  imagemia = document.getElementById("mario");
  imagemons = document.getElementById("monstruo");

  abc = micanvas.getContext("2d");
  mos = micanvas.getContext("2d");
  posY = 10;
  posX = 650;

  abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
  mos.drawImage(imagemons, monsX, monsY, 60, 60);

}




window.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
  let key = event.key;
  if (key == "ArrowDown") {
    posY = Number(posY) + 10;
    micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
    abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
    abc.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
  }

  if (key == "ArrowRight") {
    abc.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
    posX = Number(posX) + 10;
    micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
    abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
  }

  if (key == "ArrowLeft") {
    posX = Number(posX) - 10;
    micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
    abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
    abc.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
  }


  if (key == "ArrowUp") {
    posY = Number(posY) - 10;
    abc.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
    micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
    abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
  }
})

function derecha() {
  posX = Number(posX) + 10;
  micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
  abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
  mos.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
}
function izquierda() {
  posX = Number(posX) - 10;
  micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
  abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
}
function abajo() {
  posY = Number(posY) + 10;
  micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
  abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
  mos.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
}
function arriba() {
  mos.drawImage(imagemons, 10, 10, 60, 60);
  posY = Number(posY) - 10;
  micanvas.width = micanvas.width;
  abc.drawImage(imagemia, posX, posY, 40, 40);
}
```

```css
body{
background-image: url(https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/pared-de-ladrillo-azul-dibujo-retro-c-mico-del-ejemplo-arte-pop-la-historieta-148297328.jpg);
display: absolute;
}
img{
width:0;
}
```

```html
<img id="mario" src=http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1Zz2neo1Cjst8t3fOB72RGL3JAdkSwck_><br><br>
<img id="monstruo" src=http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1IeeCkdR9PM4QQx9geIprff8-bAal3PHC>

<table border="4" style="border:solid red 4px;" align="center">
  <tr align="center">
    <td ROWSPAN="3"><INPUT type="button" value="IZQUIERDA" onclick="izquierda()"
        style="border-radius: 4px; width:120; height:40; cursor: pointer; "></td>
    <td><INPUT type="button" value="ARRIBA" onclick="arriba()"
        style="border-radius: 4px; width: 120; height:40; cursor: pointer; ">
    </td>
    <TD rowspan="3"><INPUT type="button" value="DERECHA" onclick="derecha()"
        style="border-radius: 4px; width: 120; height:40; cursor: pointer; "></TD>
  </tr>
  <TR align="center">
    <TD>
      <canvas id="areainicial" width="700" height="700" style="border:solid red 4px;"></canvas>
    </TD>
  </TR>
  <TR align="center">
    <TD><INPUT type="button" value="ABAJO" onclick="abajo()"
        style="border-radius: 4px; width: 120; height:40; cursor: pointer; "> </TD>
  </TR>
</table>
```

Estoy empezando en esto de canvas y no tengo mucho conocimiento con las funciones de canvas, e investigado mucho y no encontré la manera de solucionar el error

Comment: Te recomiendo echar un vistazo a [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169125/colisiones-con-javascript-y-canvas/169157#169157)

Comment: @PabloLozano,¿ habrá alguna manera de que no se salga del canvas?

Comment: Comprobando que la posición no exceda el tamaño del canvas